# Matlab efficient for loop possible or many needed?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

```
for i = 1:length(startIdx)
    for j = 1:length(date(startIdx(i):cutoffIdx(i)))
        k = date(startIdx(i):cutoffIdx(i));
        try
            shortIdx(j)=find(and(and(and(and(and(jam>=1.2,jam<=2.3),expiration==xDates(i)),option_type=='c'),jamSym==1),quote_date==k(j)),1);
        catch
            warning('Not present')
            shortIdx(j)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

Let's say `i` = 1:4. On the first pass through i, everything is fine. But when `i` = 2, I am overwriting the stored shortIdx data I created when `i` was 1. `j` is the length of each `i`, and `k` is the dates for each `i`. Where I get tripped up is the last part of the try statement

```
quote_date==k(j)
```

because when `i` turns to 2, `j` is reset to 1. So even though `k` is the correct set of dates for `i`, I am simply overwriting the `shortIdx` variable, instead of appending to it. Is there a way for me to solve this efficiently? Or do I need to create an independent for loop for each `i`? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you are right I corrected that.

Comment: Why are you doing and() instead of & ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save into a 2D array indexed by `i` and `j`. On each pass of the inner loop

```
shortIdx(i, j) = someObscenelyLongAndStatement;
```

For efficiency you should preallocate `shortIdx` before the loops.

Alternatively, you could make a long 1D array, the update indices would be

```
shortIdx(length(startIdx)*(i- 1) + j) = ...
```

Good luck!